# Exc_bad_instruction with SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, swrevealviewcontroller, exc-bad-instruction

**Background**
My app has one MainViewController with a UIButton which leads to another ViewController when pressed. In the second ViewController is a UIBarButtonItem which has a "Back" segue to the MainViewController. Everything has worked fine, until now when I programmed a slide out menu with help from SWRevealViewController and I followed this Jared Davidson tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8EFfPT3UeWs (simple, general and easy)

**Problem**
The slide out menu works perfectly, but now when the "Back" button in the second ViewController is pressed crashes the app due to

> EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

from the following code in the MainViewController file, regarding the pan gesture for the slide out menu.

**Code**

This is my MainViewControllers code regarding my slide out menu. It works perfectly, but it inferrers with the simple "Back" segue on the second ViewController.

```
@IBOutlet weak var Open: UIBarButtonItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Open.target = self.revealViewController()
    Open.action = Selector("revealToggle:")

self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer()) //THIS IS THE CODE WHERE THE ERROR ALEERT OCCURS

}
```

When the last line of code is deleted works the "Back" segue again, but obviously not the slide out menu.

**Help**
Is it possible specify the pan gesture code to only the MainViewController and its slide out menu, and let the "Back" segue only show the MainViewController like before and/or "ignore" this line of code. 
Or is it possible in some other way to separate this two and avoid my app from crashing when the "Back" segue from the second ViewController (back to the MainViewController) is pressed?

Thanks in advance legends.

Comment: Did you find a workaround?

Comment: No, still struggling and would appreciate all the help I could get.

Comment: I had this error because my `@IBOutlet` was nil (`Open` in your case). Did you check `UIViewController` instantiation?

Comment: No that's unfortunately not it... The problem must be with the `self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())` When the BackButton is pressed it's confused by the pangesture and the app crashes... Isn't there any way around it? Maybe specify the gesture for only view/Open button? Or maybe tell the BackButton to "ignore" it? (I have tried to find a if statement, but without success :-( ) Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Hey again, @Leo I'm quite new to this and not that familiar with ´UIViewController´ instantiation. Would really appreciate if you could specify what you meant regarding your previous similar problem. How do I check the ´UIViewController´ instantiation and what is it? Thank you.

Comment: Look at my answer. If you want more real time communication you can write me mail to sokolov.lev95@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to check `Open` is nil. This error may occur when `UIViewController` was created not properly. Try this code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var Open: UIBarButtonItem?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if Open == nil {
        assertionFailure("Open is nil")
    }

    if let revealViewController = revealViewController() {
        Open?.target = revealViewController
        Open?.action = "revealToggle:"

        view.addGestureRecognizer(revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer())
    }
}
```